# Magento 2 Admin Grid Date Filter

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, order-grid, date

Using Magento 2.3.1

When admin locale is en_GB it processes dates wrong.
For example filtering orders by date.
The date pickers work correctly so the 1st May comes out as 1/5/2019 but Magento processes this as if it were an American date, e.g. January 5th

If I change to en_US locale it works consistently but I would like to use en_GB.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check the time zone set for en_GB? Can you confirm it is gmt Europe/London?

Comment: Have you ever found a fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answer you should look for time zone settings within magento and on the server where it's being hosted. Make sure all matches.